# How to structure a request to neutrinoapi using python 3? (convert urllib2 request to urllib)

Tags: python, python-3.x, urllib2, urllib

Im new to server side code and interested in using the neutrinoapi (www.neutrinoapi.com) for filtering some bad words out of text. I have written the following code in Python 3 (im using bottle server):

```
url = 'https://neutrinoapi.com/bad-word-filter'
params = {
    'user-id': 'testing',
    'api-key': '205cmqorLBdyV2F9FX4z6NNq1Y3z8AkRTw8ImtGE2MtzxmhT',
    'ip': '162.209.104.195'
}

json_data = json.dumps(params).encode('utf8')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data = json_data)
result = json.loads(response.read())
```

This request is returning the following error:

raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 403: Forbidden

The example on the website is at this link: 
https://www.neutrinoapi.com/api/api-examples/python/

Examples provided are using python 2.7 and urllib2 which i understand is now built into urllib. Cant seem to get the request to work in Python 3. Any ideas on how to make a proper request?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Python example doesn't use JSON for the *parameters*, only for the response. You'll need to *URL encode* those parameters instead; use the [`urllib.parse.urlencode()` function](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html#urllib.parse.urlencode) for that, then encode the resulting string to bytes.

You also need to send the `content` parameter for a `bad-word-filter` request, not an IP address:

```
from urllib.parse import urlencode

url = 'https://neutrinoapi.com/bad-word-filter'
params = {
    'user-id': 'testing',
    'api-key': '<valid api key>',
    'content': 'foo bar baz'
}

encoded_params = urlencode(params).encode('utf8')
response = urllib.request.urlopen(url, data = encoded_params)
result = json.loads(response.read())
```

Comment: Thank you! this worked wonderfully. I missed it in the example, but it makes perfect sense.